# Verifying Paypal email address through Android Application

Tags: php, android, paypal

I have been trying for quite a while now to verify a user's Paypal email address that is entered on Android Application and is to be stored on server for transactions from web end.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/

This is an API that gets verification but it requires account password in header of request.
Could anyone suggest me a better way of accomplishing the task in hand as i don't want to put Paypal password on stake for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password you mentioned is not the one used to log into your PayPal account, but your API password. Please check below link for its sample codes.

https://github.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php

Comment: It turns out that I was getting to wrong perspective about this, just being cautious.